# AUTO_INCREMENT is not working in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to create a table with `AUTO_INCREMENT` option of the primary key in `MariaDB`. Here is sample db table creation :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

When i try to insert `rows` :

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('name1'), ('name2'), ('name3');
```

the `rows` are not getting saved in sequence order (starting from 1.)

I googled a lot on this and could not find any solution on this.

Any thoughts on this ?

Edit: i have corrected the insert query. Just followed mariadb documentation also. Even the insertion of rows is not coming in sequence. the maria db version is 10.1.22

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO animals (name)
VALUES ('dog'), ('cat'), ('penguin'),
       ('fox'), ('whale'), ('ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  6 | dog     |
|  9 | cat     |
| 12 | penguin |
| 15 | fox     |
| 18 | whale   |
| 21 | ostrich |
+----+---------+
```

Comment: Check [`auto_increment_increment`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#auto_increment_increment) and [`auto_increment_offset`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#auto_increment_offset) server system variables, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=26e8e38668bd90cdd7c58cdd3922e086).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a 3-node Galera cluster?  That would explain the `auto_increment_increment = 3`.

But...  You should not depend on any property of `AUTO_INCREMENT` other than the values will be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Table is created correctly

but your INSERT statement is written wrong

it should be as

INSERT INTO mytable(name) VALUES ('name1'), ('name2'),('name3');

for multiple data insertion in your table

Comment: Hi Sandeep, sorry my syntax.. i edited my question. The sequence is not working properly with maria db (10.1.22)